# How to implement tableau like parameters in apache superset?

Tags: apache-superset, url-parameters

I am a beginner in superset and I want to add tableau like parameters in superset but unable to do so. tried url parameter but couldn't implement those.

this is what i tried(given by chatgpt)
SELECT
*
FROM
kri
WHERE
"Source" = '{{ url_params.Source }}'